# Counting consecutive repetitions of a specific character (e.g. ,)

Tags: sed, regular-expression, tr

Say I have a file with lines like the two following:

```
foo,bar,,baz,xy
foo,,bar,baz,xy,,
```

I would like to count how many times I have `,,` (two consecutive commas surrounded by any other character) in each line.

My approach so far: I thought I could first get rid of **everything** but any pair of consecutive commas on each line, **and then** replace those two commas by a single comma so that I can count them later. How can I do this?

The answer above should be (if we substitute the double comma by a single comma throwing everything else away):

```
,
,,
```

or simply:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Note that double commas in the middle of a line denotes one empty field, but double commas at the beginning or the end denotes **two** empty fields. What would you like to do at the beginning or end of a line? How many non-empty fields do you want to see on each line?

Comment: Thank you @glennjackman - That's a great observation. Counting empty fields is precisely my goal - This question is probably a victim of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @user815423426 Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Perl one-liner for the job:

```
perl -nle 'print s/(^|[^,]),,([^,]|$)/$&/g' your_file
```

Or, even shorter, with `awk`:

```
 awk -F',,' '{print NF-1}' your_file
```

The `awk` one would consider `,,,,` to be two occurrences of `,,`, while the `perl` one would not count it at all. Choose the one that suits your use case.

**Update**

From [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114964/counting-consecutive-repetitions-of-a-specific-character-e-g/114971#comment178590_114964), it seems that your original intent was to count the number of empty fields on each line. If that's the case, this Perl one-liner should help (it assumes that there are no quoted fields containing commas):

```
perl -nle 'print scalar grep {//} split/,/' your_file
```

The same in `awk` if Perl is not available:

```
awk -F, 'empty=0;{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="")empty++};{print empty}' your_file
```